# find unicode range through python script

Tags: python, css, unicode, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to find the unicode range, so that I can tag the unicode with different html tag. Since I have mixed unicodes which requires to be printed. So required different tags for different unicode so that different CSS font can be applied to these tags in template.

I am using python, flask, jinjatemplate. Just need a way out to to find the range from python script.

e.g. http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/devanagarichart.html
The unicode starts from &#x0905 as per from this link,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `ord()` function. It returns the characters numeric value and you can decide what to do with the char.

Example:

```
devanagari_letter_a = unichr(2309)
devanagari_letter_aa = unichr(2310)

print devanagari_letter_a.encode('utf-8'), 'value:', ord(devanagari_letter_a)
print devanagari_letter_aa.encode('utf-8'), 'value:', ord(devanagari_letter_aa)
```

Output:

```
अ value: 2309
आ value: 2310
```

Comment: Thanks @simon, I need a whole bunch of Devnagari vocabulari to test, so I think I can check with the unicode database I found at  
ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

Comment: Yes, exactly. But pay attention to the base of the numbers. The ord() returns number base of 10 but in the unicode database the numbers stored in hexadecimal format. 0905 = hex(2309) and 2309 = int('0905', 16)